# Can t use Java library in android application

Tags: java, android, jar

I use the JSOUP library for parsing html in an android application. I have created a lib folder in which I put the .jar file and then I added to Buildpath as explained in this [Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2010/02/11/java-library-jar-android/) . When I write code that includes objects and methods from the imported library I get no complaints in Eclipse, but when I run it I get this error.

```
11-25 01:05:16.108: E/AndroidRuntime(785): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-25 01:05:16.108: E/AndroidRuntime(785): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.Jsoup
11-25 01:05:16.108: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.example.seminarska.Prevozi.onCreate(Prevozi.java:76)
11-25 01:05:16.108: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
11-25 01:05:16.108: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
11-25 01:05:16.108: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
11-25 01:05:16.108: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
11-25 01:05:16.108: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-25 01:05:16.108: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
11-25 01:05:16.108: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-25 01:05:16.108: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-25 01:05:16.108: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-25 01:05:16.108: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 01:05:16.108: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-25 01:05:16.108: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-25 01:05:16.108: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-25 01:05:16.108: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put jar in libs folder and then Project -> Properies -> Java Buid Path -> Add JARs -> Select jar of your library from libs folder -> OK.

Comment: maybe but, as for the turtorial lib folder instead of libs (this changed around API 14)

Comment: You were right the error was because the folder was named lib, but it should have been libs.

Answer (score 4):

You follow this steps to add external jar in your project

Step 1

[image]

Step2
[image]

Step3

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding libraries, the correct way to do it is by copying them to the lib folder, and not the Buildpath. This changed around API 14, so there's still a fair bit of confusion about it. Follow these instructions:

1. Remove all things from the build path.
2. Create a folder named libs, if it doesn't exist. It should be at the same level as res, src, etc.
3. Place all of your library functions in this folder.